# A Java client for LDAP

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap, client

I need to write some Java code to connect to an LDAP server to verify that the user supplied LDAP account info is correct, and then I need to get attribute names from the server which this user can see. Is there some recommended Java client library for this ? If yes, which one ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Novell provides an LDAP library that you could use for this purpose:

http://blogs.oracle.com/marginNotes/entry/ldap_client_apis

There are also a couple of other options, detailed here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389746/ldap-java-library

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend, as have some others, the [UnboundID LDAP SDK](https://www.unboundid.com/products/ldapsdk/).

Generally, I would recommend avoiding JNDI for new code in favor of the UnboundID LDAP SDK for the following reasons.

The UnboundID LDAP SDK:

- is cleaner
- is clearer
- has support for failover and load-balancing
- has support for localization
- makes the use of matching rules easy
- supports a shorter learning curve, easier to use than JNDI
- supports asynchronous operations
- supports in-memory directory server, which can be useful in unit testing
- The UnboundID LDAP SDK also provides packages that assist developers with migrating away from the Netscape LDAP SDK and JNDI.

There are examples at the [blog](http://ff1959.wordpress.com), and at the sample code [site](https://code.google.com/p/ldap-sample-code/source/browse/).

If you plan to use Maven, the dependency is:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.unboundid</groupId>
  <artifactId>unboundid-ldapsdk</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

#### see also

- [LDAP: Programming Practices](http://www.ldapguru.info/ldap/ldap-programming-practices.html)

Comment: See Also link is broken.

Answer (score 2):

A very nice ldap api is the unboundid ldap sdk:

http://www.unboundid.com/products/ldapsdk/

Answer (score 1):

JLDAP from OpenLDAP: http://www.openldap.org/jldap/ is a good library.

Answer (score 1):

Just use JNDI with the LDAP provider.

Comment: Hi EJP, thanks for the answer, but I'm not sure how to use JNDI from within RAP framework.

Comment: JNDI is part of the JDK. You just write code.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend opends-sdk client api. It's fast, easy and free (under CDDL). 
Novell  and jndi are old, 
unbound is good but beware of the license requirements.

Answer (score 0):

As I'm a spring fetishist, I'd suggest to use Spring LDAP :p

http://www.springsource.org/ldap

Especially if you're already using spring for your application.

cheers

Comment: Hi chzbrgla, thanks for the answer. However I'm using RAP for my project and it will take me some time to integrate it with Spring. But I too love Spring! :)

Answer (score 0):

[Spring LDAP configuration tutorial](http://www.imrantariq.com/blog/?p=726) will help you implementing a Java client for LDAP.